# What is Reinforcement machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning

I know about supervised and unsupervised learning but still not getting how Reinforcement machine learning works.

can somebody help me with proper example ? and use cases that how it works ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/reinforcement-learning/info

Answer (score 2):

Reinforcement machine learning is when the machine learns from experience, where the feedback is "good" or "bad".

A classic example is when training agents for games. You first start training your agent with the data you have (supervised), and when it is exhausted, start training several agents and let the compete each other. Those who win are getting "reinforced", and go on.

This was one of the "tricks" used to [train AlphaGo](https://www.tastehit.com/blog/google-deepmind-alphago-how-it-works/), (and previously in [TD-Gammon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TD-Gammon))

> ...
>   The policy networks were therefore
>   improved by letting them play against each other, using the outcome of
>   these games as a training signal. This is called reinforcement
>   learning, or even deep reinforcement learning (because the networks
>   being trained are deep).

Comment: While i do like many of your answers, i'm not that satisfied with this one. Of course it's hard to summarize such a complex topic but i don't like the wording and examples. (1) ```the feedback is "good" or "bad"``` This indicates a binary reward, but RL is based on numerical rewards (more general). (2) *Game example 1*: Of course this supervised pre-learning is optional (and a good idea if data is available). But it's not needed. (3) *Game ex. 2: this indicates some ensemble or multi-agent setting, which is possible. But of course a single agent can learn too (more often used imho).

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned about supervised and unsupervised learning.
There is a slight difference in these 3.

- Supervised learning: You have label for each tuple of data.
- Unsupervised learning: You don't have label for tuples but you want to find relations between inputs
- Reinforcement leaning: You have very few labels for sparse entries. that label is rewards.

reinforcement learning is a process how a person learns about a new situation. it takes any random action, observe the behavior of the environment and learns accordingly.

What is a reward.?

a reward is positive or negative feedback from the environment. An action is responsible for all its future rewards. hence it need to take those action which can achieve most positive reward in future.

This can be achieve by Q-learning algorithm. i request you to check about this topic.

I used reinforcement algorithm to train pacman. i hope you know the game. the goal is to take action by which it should not hit the ghosts and also should be able to take all points from the map. it train itself after many iterations and thousands of gameplay. I also used same to train a car to drive on a specific track!

The reinforcement learning can be used to train an AI to learn any game.! Though more complex games require Neural Networks, and that is called Deep learning.

Answer (score 1):

Reinforcement learning is a type of model that is rewarded for doing good (or bad) things. With supervised learning, it is up to some curator to label all the data that the model can learn from. That is the beauty of reinforcement learning, **the model obtains direct feedback from its environment and adjusts its behavior automatically.** It's how human's learn a lot of our simple life lessons (e.g., avoid things that hurt you, do more of things that make you feel good)

A lot of reinforcement learning is focused around deep learning these days and the biggest examples have been about video games. Reinforcement learning is also a powerful personalization tool. You can think of an amazon recommender as a reinforcement learning algorithm that is rewarded when it recommends the right products by receiving a click or purchase, or a netflix recommender is rewarded when a user starts watching a movie.

Answer (score 1):

Reinforcement learning is often used for robotics, gaming, and navigation.

With reinforcement learning, the algorithm discovers through trial and error which actions yield the greatest rewards.

This type of learning has three primary components: the agent (the learner or decision-maker), the environment (everything the agent interacts with) and actions (what the agent can do).

The objective is for the agent to choose actions that maximize the expected reward over a given amount of time.

The agent will reach the goal much faster by following a good policy. So the goal in reinforcement learning is to learn the best policy.